# DB adapter receives duplicate rows from DB2 table

Tags: db2, soa, jdeveloper, osb

It is 11g version..

A DB adapter has been created with operation type as to perform SELECT operation on the DB2 table/view. The DB2 table/view does not have the PRIMARY KEY column defined in the database. But we have a step in the DB adapter configuration wizard where it is required to select the primary key column of the table/view (if the primary key is already defined, it will be selected by default). Let the DB2 view has data something like below.

A|B |C
1|X1|2.2
1|Y1|4.6
1|Z1|4.6
1|X1|3.3
1|Z1|(null)

The Primary key column is selected as 'B' just to proceed to the next step as there isn't really a column with unique values.
Now when the business service of this case is executed in the OSB console the response is received with duplicate rows as below.

```
<collection><br/>
<row><br/>
<A>1</A><br/>
<B>X1</B><br/>
<C>2.2</C><br/>
</row><br/>
<row><br/>
<A>1</A><br/>
<B>Y1</B><br/>
<C>4.6</C><br/>
</row><br/>
<row><br/>
<A>1</A><br/>
<B>Z1</B><br/>
<C>4.6</C><br/>
</row><br/>
<row><br/>
<A>1</A><br/>
<B>X1</B><br/>
<C>2.2</C><br/>
</row><br/>
<row><br/>
<A>1</A><br/>
<B>Z1</B><br/>
<C>4.6</C><br/>
</row><br/>
</collection>
```

As seen from the response XML it is clear that the  same data present in the table is not fetched exactly. (i.e.) if there are two rows for which the value of B is X1 but different values of A & C, the response has two rows but with the value of A,B & C of only the first row (as shown for values of C in above XML for X1 and Z1)

There is also way to select multiple columns as to create composite primary key but all the three columns cannot be selected as primary key as the column C will have some data that can be (null) which will throw error as the primary key column cannot have null values.

Only the columns A and B can be selected as composite primary key then the response XML would have 5 records in XML but with the data of first row in all the five records as the value of A is same for all the rows.

Hope i am able explain the problem to make everyone understand. Please comment in your thoughts and ideas if you have ever faced the same or similar issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the source-data is non-unique, and for some reason you need a unique column then why not add a surrogate key when fetching from the source data (e.g. row_number() etc.) ?

Comment: We have requested the same to the customer but the customer is like why cant we do it without a unique column..you know customers always want to test the developers..

Comment: Why should they care if the surrogate-key is invisible to them (i.e. not persistent in the database) ?

Comment: Actually we use Oracle DB adapter to create a webservice that fetches the data from the table and it is created in Jdeveloper tool which is more like a configuration wizard clicking next..next..finish.. In this wizard, it only lists the visible columns present in the table. It is not possible to select that column unless and until it is made a regular column of the table. They dont want to add a new column that would have the ROW_NUMBER() values as the table is already used in different applications.

Comment: Why not create a view on the source-data where the view includes the surrogate definition ? (in that way, there is no persistent surrogate). The adapter could then reference that new view.

Comment: being a beginning SOA developer I am not aware of DB2 concepts much..Thanks for the suggestion ...I would suggest that to the customer..

Comment: Side note: If you don't have a stable thing to order on, `ROW_NUMBER()` is going to give non-deterministic (essentially, random) results.  You have that now, of course (There is no such thing as a 'first' row in SQL).  Your best hope is they have some sort of timestamp, at minimum.  Although, this is DB2, so they probably have `RRN` (which returns the 'physical row on disk', more or less), and would at least be stable until they re-org the table...